# Firefox does not animate when <g> component attributes change

Tags: reactjs, animation, svg, transition

I'm creating some animated React components in SVG. When I run it **in Chrome, the animation works**, but when I run it in Firefox, it doesn't.

Here is an example:

```
const [x, setX] = useState(0)

useEffect(() => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    setX(100)
  }, 3000)
}, [])

return (
  <svg width={500} height={300}>
    <g transform={`translate(${x}, ${0})`} style={{ transition: "3s all" }}>
      <rect width={50} height={50} x={0} y={0} fill={'#f00'} />
    </g>
  </svg>
)
```

You can see that it works in Chrome, but not in Firefox: https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-ives-ykmfp

If I remove the transform in **g** and change direct in x prop of the **rect**, that way will work in Firefox, but I don't want to do it that way.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `transform` attribute is not the same as the `transform` CSS property, even though it can be confusing (and apparently the two [will be merged](https://css-tricks.com/transforms-on-svg-elements/)).

Instead of using the attribute, move the transform to the style property:

```js
const [x, setX] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    setX(100);
  }, 3000);
}, []);

return (
  <svg width={500} height={300}>
    <g style={{ transform: `translate(${x}px, 0px)`, transition: 'all 3s' }}>
      <rect width={50} height={50} x={0} y={0} fill={'#f00'} />
    </g>
  </svg>
);
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-snowflake-664rk

Answer (score 0):

Try to move the transform property to the style. It works for me this way in FF.:

```
<g style={{transform: `translateX(${x}px)`, transition: "3s all" }}>
  <rect width={50} height={50} x={0} y={0} fill={"#f00"} />
</g>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-cdn-7eqg0